# Col 6 Panels Alignment Issues

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

First experience with bootstrap. Want 2 panels next to each other using the col-lg-6 class. Left panel will be a link to an article while holding an image. Right will be a signup/login box. 
When loading the site the 2 panel goes underneath?

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h2>Lastest News</h2>
                <p>Article</p>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Panel Header</div>
                <div class="panel-body"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/warning.png"</div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <form action="/action_page.php">
                    <h2>Buy, Sell and more deals!</h2>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                        <li>
                            <button class="navbutton"> 
                                Login
                            </button>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p> Not with us yet? </p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button class="navbutton"> 
                                Sign Up
                            </button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is all inside a container.

[Before adding img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCzmQ.png)

[After adding img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8SJB.png)

Comment: Your `img` is not closed in reference code

Comment: Oh my goodness gracious me thank you, sorry for being so blind.

Comment: Does that solve your issue?

Comment: Yes it does. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h2>Lastest News</h2>
        <p>Article</p>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Panel Header</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/warning.png"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <form action="/action_page.php">
            <h2>Buy, Sell and more deals!</h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <li>
                    <button class="navbutton"> 
                                Login
                            </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p> Not with us yet? </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button class="navbutton"> 
                                Sign Up
                            </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes my formatting was all over the place. Fixed it while I waited for answers. Didn't close img like a numpty which would've been obvious if I did in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: Tip: Always use indentation and format your code correctly. This avoids most of such issues.

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma, Always prefer to explain your answer, to make user clear about what issue he/she was facing.

Comment: I have proceeded to use the auto formatting for html in vscode so hopefully this shouldn't happen again and I'll come back with a real issue :p Thank you both.